# Сумма найденых элементов

Tags: php, битрикс

В битриксе через CIBlockElement::GetList вывожу полученные элементы

```
<?
                $arSelect = Array("ID", "NAME", "DETAIL_PAGE_URL", "DETAIL_PICTURE", "CATALOG_GROUP_1");
                $arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>4, "ID"=>$arAnalogsIDs, "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", "ACTIVE"=>"Y", ">DETAIL_PICTURE"=>"0" );
                $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize"=>6), $arSelect);
                while($ob = $res->GetNextElement())
                {
                    $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
                    ?>
                    <div class="media">
                        <div class="pull-left">
                            <a href="<?=$arFields["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>">
                                <img class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64" style="width: 74px; height: 74px;" src="<?=CFile::GetPath($arFields["DETAIL_PICTURE"])?>" data-holder-rendered="true" alt="<?=$arFields["NAME"]?>" title="<?=$arFields["NAME"]?>"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h5 class="media-heading"><?=$arFields["NAME"]?></h5>
                                <span class="price"><?=$arFields["CATALOG_PRICE_1"]?></span>    
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <?}?>
```

Как мне получить сумму $arFields["CATALOG_PRICE_1"] всех найденных элементов ?
Заранее спасибо за помощь !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//......
$sum = 0;
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement())
{
  $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
  $sum+=$arFields["CATALOG_PRICE_1"];
  //.....
}
```